# secrets-gradle-plugin not working with Android manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, secret-key

Following https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin I'm trying to move my API key to the local.properties file, however, when I try to use the variable in my manifest file I get this error :

```
"Attribute meta-data#API_KEY@value at AndroidManifest.xml:20:13-44 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <KEY_VALUE> is provided."
```

Here are my files:

Project build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}
```

Module build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
```

local.properties:

```
KEY_VALUE= MY_API_KEY
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="API_KEY"
            android:value="${KEY_VALUE}"/>
</application>
```

Comment: This example clearly shows how to correctly configure the Gradle Biuld files to add a mapview configuration for android studio.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, on a side note I find this Google Library buggy and obsolete - it has not been updated for two years now - plus I couldn't make it work for me. What worked for me is the implementation on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77647537/7839518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was finally able to fix the issue. It seems like there's somewhat of a bug with the plugin. For it to work you have to add it after the android plugin so the ordering of the plugins within the grade file of your app module is actually important.

Answer (score -1):

Try to rebuild your project and run again.If still you get this error add new properties file in your project named `local.defaults.properties` below `local.properties` file.
In that file add KEY_VALUE="Your map key" and
in `build.gradle`(app level) add

```
secrets {
    defaultPropertiesFileName 'local.defaults.properties'
}
```

after dependencies block,
Now rebuild and run your project.Hope it will help.