# Hide Google Maps Key in AndroidManifest from Exposure in Public Repos

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

Believe me that I have looked at every SO Question on this subject but can't get the Google Map to display when I hide the map key away from the AndroidManifest.xml.

I have also looked the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests#inject_build_variables_into_the_manifest) but I am still stuck hence the reason for posting this.

**mapskey.property file** (*have also tried with local.properties file to no avail*)

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = "ABCD1234" # not the actual key obviously
```

The idea is to put `mapskey.properties` file on `.gitignore` therefore keeping it away from the version control.

**AndroidManifest.xml** code snippet:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  ....
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="${googleKey}"/>
```

**build.gradle.kts** file code snippet:

```
android {

 defaultConfig { ...

                 //load the values from .properties file
                  val mapsKeyFile = project.rootProject.file("mapskey.properties")
                  val properties = Properties()
                      properties.load(mapsKeyFile.inputStream())

                 //fetch the map key
                 val mapKey = properties.getProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: ""

                //create a map of manifest placeholders
                   manifestPlaceholders["googleKey"] = mapKey

               //define the resource value
                 resValue(type = "string", name = "googleKey", value = mapKey)
```

I have tried to use **`manifestPlaceholder[]`** alone but the map did not display. When I used **`resValue`** alone I got this error:

> Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY@value at
> AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-40 requires a placeholder substitution but
> no value for  is provided

The only way I am getting the map to display is if I *inject the google map key directly into the manifest* or setting it *directly on the manifestHolder*.

```
// Injecting the key directly on manifestPlaceholders is working
    manifestPlaceholders["googleKey"] = "ABCD1234"
```

I have tried the code both on Physical Device and the Android Emulator with the same result. I have uninstalled/installed the app but got nowhere. I have even tested with a **`buildConfigField()/ BuildConfig`** Constant which is reading and logging the key correctly from the *mapskey.properties* file.

After all this I believe this should not count as a duplicate question as I need genuine help to pinpoint where I am falling short.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a while I realized the problem was on the `mapskey.properties` properties file. This is all thanks to the intensive debugging that I did.

I had declared the key as:

```
// I wrapped the key within String quotes
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = "ABCD1234"
```

The proper way is to declare the key without the double quotes.

```
// I wrapped the key within String quotes
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = ABCD1234
```

It was a real struggle that I can't wish on anyone else.